# Comparing tables in two different instances

Tags: kdb

I would like to compare all tables and schemas are the same in two different instances. How would I be able to iterate through that?

```
schemas:
(0# tab) ~ (h"0#tab")
```

But there are like 10 tables. whats the fastest way to compare the schemas?

Answer (score 5):

Something like the following will compare the meta's of local vs remote tables:

`/(0# tab) ~ (h"0#tab")`

`tableList:tables[]`

`tableList!{meta[x]~ @[h;"meta ",string x;0b]}each tableList`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it by using the functional form rather than passing the strings to remote handle :

```
ts!(meta each ts)~'{ @[h;(meta;x);0b] }each ts:tables[]
```

The following will make sure to compare only the tables which are available on both q sessions:

```
rtabs:h(tables;`)   / get the table list from remote session 
ts!(meta each ts)~'{ @[h;(meta;x);0b] }each ts: tables[] inter rtabs /using inter
```

Comment: Thanks! any way to compare the data in all table ?

Comment: There are multiple ways you can get it done. please post a question with some samples, I will help you out accordingly.